# how to apply two mathemtical conditions in one condition without float type error

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, boolean, dataset

i have this column of my dataframe
Datetime

```
Datetime                  kt         CMF
2022-06-09 12:33:00 0.4164263068002197  0.8847680578178683
2022-06-09 12:34:00 0.42792520202792106 0.8725120368719221
2022-06-09 12:35:00 0.5134482518105007  0.8602633894204332
2022-06-09 12:36:00 0.5306221108293145  0.8480020389466362
2022-06-09 12:37:00 0.576460973390728   0.8357518604940146
2022-06-09 12:38:00 0.5787411028480746  0.823494817828331
2022-06-09 12:39:00 0.5941322373815262  0.8112418608843985
```

what i want to do is for the rows that  cmf >= 0.8 and kt >= 0.6 in a new column to say non
blocked disk
otherwise the new column says  blocked disk

i tried this

```
frames['sun disk'] = np.where((frames['CMF'] >= 0.8 & frames['clearness index (kt)'] >= 0.6 ) , "non blocked" , 'blocked')
```

and the output is

> TypeError: Cannot perform 'rand_' with a dtyped [float64] array and scalar of type [bool]

how can i fix it ?

Comment: You need parentheses around the conditions. `&` has higher precedence than `>=`.

Comment: Each condition needs to be within ( ) brackets.

Comment: use `.ge(.8)` instead of ` >= .8` then you can forget the parentheses.

Answer (score 1):

You can add more parentheses to each condition.

```
frames['sun disk'] = np.where(((frames['CMF'] >= 0.8) & (frames['clearness index (kt)'] >= 0.6) ) , "non blocked" , 'blocked')
```